# Is the auxiliary verb "have" declared implicitly in this sentence?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, to-infinitive, repetition, gerund-clauses

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> After **having** accused the Congress of working in favour of Pakistan, it appears **to resurrected** the issue of "citizenship".

At first glance, the sentence seemed wrong to me because of the past form of a verb used after "to". But then I got to suspect that the auxiliary verb "have" was declared implicitly between the two because it had already been used before and so there was no need of it. Am I right in thinking so?

Comment: You **must** include "have". The verb phrase is ungrammatical without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is ungrammatical, it should be

> After having accused the Congress of working in favour of Pakistan, it appears to **have** resurrected the issue of "citizenship".

Comment: But, then, don't you think there was no need of using it again since it had already been used before (in "after having").

Comment: No, it appears to be a mistake in the original, a letter to a newspaper about politics. "It" refers to the ruling party.

Answer (score 0):

> it had already been used before and so there was no need of it. Am I right in thinking so?

You are partially correct.

The sentence as written is wrong, and it's wrong because of the phrase I've put in bold:

> ✘ After having accused the Congress of working in favour of Pakistan, it appears **to resurrected** the issue of "citizenship."

*One* way to fix it is to repeat *have*:

> ✔ After having accused the Congress of working in favour of Pakistan, it appears **to** ***have*** **resurrected** the issue of "citizenship."

However, there is another possibility: don't repeat *have* but change the verb tense:

> ✔ After having accused the Congress of working in favour of Pakistan, it appears **to** ***be resurrecting*** the issue of "citizenship."
>
> ✔ After having accused the Congress of working in favour of Pakistan, it appears **to** ***resurrect*** the issue of "citizenship."

---

Note that in all versions of this sentence, the referent of the pronoun **it** is unclear. (This is especially obvious in the final version that I gave.)  This is fine if there is a previous sentence that **it** is referencing.

But if there is no previous sentence, then *all* versions are badly phrased, and they should be changed to something like one of the following:

> ✔ After having accused the Congress of working in favour of Pakistan, **the issue of "citizenship" appears to** ***have been*** resurrected.
>
> ✔ Accusing the Congress of working in favour of Pakistan appears **to** ***have*** **resurrected** the issue of "citizenship."
>
> ✔ Accusing the Congress of working in favour of Pakistan appears **to** ***be resurrecting*** the issue of "citizenship."
>
> ✔ Accusing the Congress of working in favour of Pakistan appears **to** ***resurrect*** the issue of "citizenship."

Note how the inclusion or omission of *after* affects how this can be written.